# VBA to delete bookmark when Criteria not met in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I have a Word document where I have bookmarked lines of text - say 10 lines each. I have 6 of these texts lines on different pages of the word document, so I have a total of 6 bookmarks in the entire Word document. Now given certain criteria in Excel, say if Coulmn A1:A6 have:

```
0,1,1,1,0,1
```

Where IF cell A1 is 0 delete first bookmark named sai1, sai1.delete, If cell A2 is 1 dont delete bookmark named sai2 , if cell A3 is 1 dont delete, but if 0 delete and so on and so forth; essentially what i want is a loop to do this for 100+ some bookmarks given 100+ criteria in excel, it might be more. I could not find an easier way beside if-else statement. I will really appreciate the help.
here is my code so far:

```
Set wtb1 = wdd.Bookmarks("D043").Range
Set wtb2 = wdd.Bookmarks("D044").Range
Set wtb3 = wdd.Bookmarks("D018").Range
Set wtb4 = wdd.Bookmarks("D046").Range
If Sheets("CPA").Cells(426, 7).Value = 0 Then
         wtb1.Delete
         ElseIf Sheets("CPA").Cells(427, 7).Value = 0 Then
               wtb2.Delete
         ElseIf Sheets("CPA").Cells(428, 7).Value = 0 Then
               wtb3.Delete
         ElseIf Sheets("CPA").Cells(429, 7).Value = 0 Then
               wtb4.Delete
End If
```

Is there a For loop method to tackle this? I also tried doing this:

```
 For k = 426 To 429
 If Sheets("CPA").Cells(k, 7).Value = 0 Then

     'Sheets("CPA").Cells(i, 10) = Sheets("CPA").Cells(i, 9).Value
     Value1 = Sheets("CPA").Cells(426, 9).Value
     Value1(i).Text.Delete
     i = i + 1
     End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this should get you what you need:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ManageBookmarks()

Dim wdApp   As Object
Dim wdDoc   As Object
Dim wdName  As String
Dim wdTemp  As Object
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i       As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
wdName = "C:\Test.docx" 'Your file path here

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wdName)
    wdApp.Visible = True
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    For Each wdTemp In wdApp.Documents
        If StrComp(wdTemp.FullName, wdName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set wdDoc = wdTemp
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wdTemp
    If wdDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wdName)
    End If
End If

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
            If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("sai" & i) = True Then
                wdDoc.Bookmarks("sai" & i).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

This code assumes that your list of zeros and ones are in column A starting in row 1.

Put this code in your Excel file, set your worksheet to what you want, add your file name for `wdName` and you should be all set.